# Laravel 5: get the model of a relation with different id

Tags: laravel, relationship, primary-key

I have a model contract and a model member.
Each contract has a mainmember but can have a submember.

Therefore my table contract has a member_id and a subMember_id.
It is no Problem to get the mainmember (member_id) but how can I get the second member with the subMember_id?

Thanks for help ...

class Contract:

```
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
    }

    public function getMember($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($id);

        foreach($contract->members as $member) {
        return $member->name;
    }

    }

    public function getSubMember($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($id);
        $primaryKey = 'subMember_id';

        foreach($contract->members::with('subMember_id')->get() as $member) {
        return $member->name;
    }
    }
}
```

class Member:

```
class Member extends Model
{

public function contracts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contract');
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a relationship between Contract and Member based on submember_id primary key from Contract.

In classs Contract

```
protected function SubMember(){

   return $this->hasMany('App\Member','Member_id ','SubMember_id ');
}
```

After that you can use this

```
$contract = Contract::find($someID);

$subMemeberId = $contract->SubMember->Member_id;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'members.subMember_id ' ... 
tried:
 public function getSubMember($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($id)->subMember->subMember_id;
        
        foreach($contract->members as $member) {
        return $member->name;
    }
    }

Did you mean this? Unfortunately not working ..

Comment: You have column named subMember_id in Members?

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer, you should invert foreign key with primary in relationship.
Now it should work.

Comment: Not sure if I did understand you the wright way ..
in contract:
function subMember() like you did and

    public function getSubMember($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($id)->subMember->subMember_id;
        
        foreach($contract->members as $member) {
           return $member->name;
        }
    }
in Blade-template:

    {{$contract->getSubMember($contract->id)}}
throws 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'members.Member_id '

Comment: In Members you have Member_id as a column?
I've just established a relationship between Contracts and Members based on SubMember_Id (from Contracts) -> Member_id (from Members) columns.
after that this, Contract->subMember->Member_id;  should return all Submembers_id's associated to the Contract

Comment: I edited (again) my answer $subMembersID = Contract->SubMember->Member_id  is the correct way. $subMembers is a collection with all the submembers id's for that Contract.

Comment: unfortunately I get an error:
    ErrorException (E_ERROR)
    syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')'

when I use: $subMembersID = Contract->SubMember->Member_id

Comment: Of course it should have ; at the end $subMembersID = Contract->SubMember->Member_id; 
If you use in a view than it should be {{ $subMembersID = Contract->SubMember->Member_id;  }}

Comment: of course ... but I get the same error ...

my members-table has an id, changed it to member_id, but got the same error ..

Comment: Try this $contract = Contract::find($someID); $subMemeberId = $contract->SubMember->Member_id; and take about case sensitive. If the column name is Member_id (in members table)  than it should be like that over all and in the relationship definition also.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I will test it. For the moment I solved it by getting the subMember_id from the contract-table and calling the member directly with that id. Not that elegant, but it works ...

Comment: Please do :) 
I'm very curios:) It was my error that first I did not instantiate CONTRACT as an object $contract .....